What functions would I use alongside Match, Index, and Large functions for specifically doing date based filtration?
I have people's names in the columns. Under each name are rows with the week and then a number under each column name. I want to find a formula that can auto-calculate the top 3 names of the values for a specific week I select. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The code I've used to get names so far, but not date-dependent, is:
=INDEX(G3:L3,MATCH(LARGE(G4:L4,B8)G4:L4,0))

G3:L3 equals names of people, G4:L4 equals values, B8 equals position 2 of 3 largest values.
I want to have a date beside the G4:L4 values and to be able to select a date and for it to pick the top three names by value.

Please read [ask] and [mre] and Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question and [edit] your question to include code and data as text, not images and enough information (e.g. expected output) to make it possible to answer your question.


in c2: =MATCH(B2, F4:F10, 0) + 3 to understand in which row that date is referring to, like in f4 is the selected date b2 is referring to, so 4 is the value
in c3: =LARGE(INDEX(G$4:L$10, C$2 - 3, 0), 1) the value that is the largest
in d3: =INDEX($G$3:$L$3, MATCH(C3, INDEX(G$4:L$10, C$2 - 3, 0), 0)) expected name which has that value.
just change the last 1 to 2 and 3 for the later positions. it'll work up to 10 rows, so if you need more, increase the number. Just changing the date value in B2 will automatically update all the expected values from the formulas.
simply can copy those formulas from here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uulx_QqoK4cCurK9_Of757grMdzI5ly1YUHYuzUVe2I/edit?usp=sharing

Hi thanks for replying it gives me the top name in the 1st row yes, but it's not date dependant.

updated the detailed answer for you

Hi Towsif, I am hoping I got your 1st name right, I can't actually believe this, you honestly have made my week solving this, I cannot thankyou enough for your support !!!!!!! I really appreciate it.

You're welcome ^_^ you can upvote the answer then accept it as answer to close this issue, if this answer satisfies the problem
